# 'FBSDKAppEvents.h' file not found when using cocoapods for facebookSDK

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, cocoapods, facebook-login

I am trying to update FacebookSDK using cocoapods in my RN app and i keep getting error:

'FBSDKAppEvents.h' file not found.

at file FBSDKCoreKit.h

My pod file is

```html
target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end
```

Comment: I assume you ran `pod install` ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: This suggests that it may be related to RN versions < .60 https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/636

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm experiencing the same

Answer (score 1):

try with this pod

```
target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'FacebookSDK'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end
```

Comment: Same error unfortunately, i also tried to clear derived data and build folder but error remains. Thanks for your reply